# Is it possible to receive errors in queue manager logs for channels which are not existing?

Tags: ibm-mq

Could you please help in checking, why we receive 'AMQ9519: Channel 'A.B' not found' errors in queue manager logs though the channel is not existing on both sides. I checked if we are receiving this error if there is a receiver channel existing on remote side, but remote side confirmed that there is no receiver channel existing. Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The error `AMQ9519` should be proceeded by an error `AMQ9780`.

For example the error below would proceed the channel not found error.

```
AMQ9780: Channel to remote machine '10.9.8.7' is ending due to an error.

EXPLANATION:
Channel 'A.B' between this machine and the remote machine
'10.9.8.7' encountered an error and will now end. In some cases the
channel name can not be determined and so is shown as '????'.
```

Based on this error you can tell the source IP of the remote machine attempting to connect to the channel that does not exist on your queue manager.

Note that the same pair of error is produced no matter what type of channel the remote machine is attempting to connect to.  It could be produced for any of the following:

```
RCVR     (Connected to by remote SDR or SVR channel)
RQSTR    (Connected to by remote SDR or SVR channel)
SVR      (Connected to by remote RQSTR channel)
SDR      (Connected to by remote RQSTR channel)
CLUSRCVR (Connected to by remote CLUSSDR channel)
SVRCONN  (Connected to by remote MQ client application)
```

The common causes I have noted for this problem:

1. A `SDR` channel on the remote machine where the local `RCVR` does not exist, this could be because the `RCVR` was removed or because the `SDR` has a typo in the channel name.
2. A MQ Client application is specifying the name of a `SVRCONN` that does not exist, this could be because the `SVRCONN` was removed or because the client has a typo in the name of the `SVRCONN` channel they are specifying.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, there is an xmitq still existing which has this channel name set in trigdata. Hence we are receiving those errors. Thank you for your inputs